# Isn't S a literal type?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

This code doesn't compile in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8f2bc93290c69c0), although it seems to comply with iso §5.19 p2 9th bullet point and iso §3.9 p10, i.e., `S` is a literal type and so, `S a(1);` should be considered a constant expression. In particular, iso §3.9 p10 bullet point 3 doesn't say anything about unitialized members.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int i;
    float x;

    constexpr S(int j) : i{j} {}
};    

int main()
{
    constexpr S a(1);
}
```

Comment: Goofus writes *"Does't compile"*, but doesn't provide the compiler error.   Gallant always puts relevant details in his posts.

Comment: clang-500.2.79 doesn't like it either: adding `x()` to the initializer list fixes it.

Comment: Clang even gives the correct error message, as in "constexpr constructor must initialize all members".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is standardized in 7.1.5/4 ([dcl.constexpr], "The `constexpr` specifier"):

> The definition of a *constexpr* constructor shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - [...]
> - every non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized
> - [...]